# Run Specflow test multiple times from database

Tags: specflow

I am new to specflow and trying to understand if it is possible to get 
the values to pass to test from database.

Eg: Add two numbers
       Given I have entered #50 into the calculator
       And I have also entered 70 into the calculator
       When I press add
       Then the result should be 120 on the screen

I want logic where I can search a specific table in db for ID "50" and execute the test for all the records returned.

I am able to do this in mstest but not sure if this is possible with Specflow.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Thanks,
Satty

Comment: If you could show us an example of what you are doing in MSTest vs what you have tried in specflow, we might be able to help you a little better

Comment: Agreed that without some more information this is very difficult to answer. I don't think this is going to be possible very easily though, at least not very cleanly

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely possible, however its not contingent on specflow.

What I mean by that is that specflow is just a wrapper. Its up to you to write that logic for how that step is implemented. Think of your StepDefs as unit tests in MSTest, and carry that logic over.

You said you are able to do this in MSTest. The process should be almost exactly the same in SpecFlow